# Interview question regarding the performance of a process

Tags: c++, performance, unix

i have faced this question in a recent interview.

lets assume that we have a process and it can be run multiple instances.
after having some discussions we have decided that not more than 5 instances of the process w e can run in the environment.Now if such a process is given to me  and i need to check all the possibilities to increase the performance of the process.

i answered that we need to check if there are any unneccessary validations done in the process and try to avoid them in the code.also said that the resources should be adequate.
then he replied that if have abundant resources..then?

BTW ,lets assume that the process is developed in c++.

could you please suggest any more ways that we need to think about the increase in performance?

**EDIT:** as per jons answer,
i had asked the same questions.and the answers to me are:
1)its a telecom billing process which processes EDR from the network.
2)most of the time it should be processing EDR's.sine we make telephone calls 24/7.
3)he simply said 5 i suppose,just that he wants only five instances.

After this edit can i have any better answers?

Comment: Emm... Profiling? Yes, profiling!

Comment: *"Remove everything redundant."* Gotta love those interview questions.

Comment: :I like your id, it goes with the word Process. `Zombie Process`

Comment: Process optimisation or tuning is more in general considered keeping in view of resource constraints (in most often cases). I would not really be considering to optimise the process when I have really abundant resources at my shop otherwise I would keep more focus on security, memory leaks and all but if the process does its job without having too much load on the system, I would not further optimise the process.. well it depends as well on who wrote the program .. is not it? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to give a meaningful answer to this question without more information. For example:

- What is the purpose of the process?
- What does the process do during most of its running time? Is it I/O bound? Is it CPU bound? Does it usually sleep and only occasionally wake up?
- What is the nature of the 5-at-most limit? Does the process enforce it internally? Is it imposed by resource considerations?

Comment: +1. That's the right answer, IMO.

Comment: I don't think purpose of the application matters. "then he replied that if have abundant resources..then?". the interviewer was probably interesting in sharing resources and data between applications..

Comment: @cprogrammer: The purpose of the application *might turn out* not to matter. The fact that someone asked or did not ask the "what's the purpose?" question during the interview *definitely* matters. It's the first question you should ask, because it will give you information on what other questions might be relevant. Did I mention you are supposed to ask lots of questions before answering this? :)

Comment: it's obvious that the discussion will go to other fields, but my guess is that "first test" was this: Doesn't matters that app do, if there are many instances, what can you do?. Any other improvement based on "what it does" will improve all the instances, so ... no point discussing about multiple instances

Comment: @cprogrammer, how does sharing of resources increase performance? I see this as adding more bottlenecks and therefore *reducing* performance... And performance in this context is pure throughput...

Comment: @Nim: depends on the context: sharing resources that don't need to be shared could add a bottleneck, but properly coordinating access to a shared scarce resource (e.g. a database connection) may improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect they are looking for an answer about sharing memory/code between the processes.

For example, a large part of the code could be placed in a DLL (or shared library), which will be shared between the processes - reducing the overall memory used.

This might also be used to coordinate access to share resources, share large heap allocations (like buffers or memory pools) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

first you should check the resources your process uses: files, reg keys, global (named) synchronization objects, etc. Anything that is shared between those instances is performance penalty.
second ... a big depends ... can be anything specific to that process

Answer (score 0):

If the instances of the process run over the same (shared) resources, than it could be a good idea to reduce the coupling between them at its minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different answers to this questions. 
Answer depends on what the process does or functional requirement ?

Depending upon the requirement different optimization are applicable.

if its simple chat server then we have to apply different optimizations
if its simple file server then we have to apply different optimization and like wise different optimizations are applicable as per functional requirement

But, in general memory optimization, leak detection, CPU optimization, thread optimization, loop detection, function optimization can be applied to generally all the programs.

again if its server or client depending upon we might have to apply different optimizations. Server is assumed to run without closing for months unlike clients.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowledge about the application we can provide only the universal points to check in C++:

- avoid unnecessary copys of objects there you could use references
- check algotithms if they are ineffective and there are easier ways
- place frequent case labels first
- minimize local variables and declare them in the inner most scope
- prefer initialization over assignment when possible
- ...